# Read a stream of objects and then update the count in the object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to parse through a list of sorted numbers, and then find out count of how many numbers are in sequence .

```
List<Integer> sortedNum = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 8, 10);
```

So in this list, i would expect the result as `{1;3},{8;1},{10;1}`.

Without streams the code looks like this,

```
Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
int i = 0;
while (true) {
  int num = sortedNum.get(i);
  int count = 0;
  while (i < sortedNum.size()) {

    count++;
    i++;

    if (i == sortedNum.size()) {
      break;
    }
    if ((sortedNum.get(i - 1) + 1) < sortedNum.get(i)) {
      break;
    }
  }
  countMap.put(num, count);
  if (i == sortedNum.size()) {
    countMap.forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println(a + " " + b));
    break;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to convert this into stream operations by iterating over IntStreams? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us on example for count usage? Also it can't be null only 0 if we use int for it. @Sneha

Comment: you meant `1,"s",2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think that this is a task which benefits from the Stream API. Still, you can simplify the code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Integer v = sortedNum.isEmpty()? null: sortedNum.get(0);
int count = 0;
for(Integer i: sortedNum) {
    if(v + count == i) count++;
    else {
        countMap.put(v, count);
        v = i;
        count = 1;
    }
}
if(v != null) countMap.put(v, count);
```

```
countMap.forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println(a + " " + b));
```

```
1 3
8 1
10 1
```

It is possible to express such an operation by implementing a custom `Collector`, but the code would be more complicated while basically doing the same as the loop body within its accumulator function. But additionally, it would require a merge function, which is not trivial for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want a new stream of NumWithValueAndCount.

The simplest way I can think of will to use map, indeed.

```
List<NumWithValueAndCount> newListOfNumWithValueAndCount = Arrays.stream(sortedArrayOfNumWithValue)
    .map(oldNum -> new NumWithValueAndCount(oldNum.getNum(), oldNum.getValue(), methodToGetCount()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Ruslan : I though the point was to get a stream of NumWithValueAndCount.
Does this answer look better ?

Comment: It is not clear from the question what is the point.. Anyway, upvoted ;)

Comment: sorry, my bad.. i hope its clear now, that i am interested in how to find the count of numbers which are in sequence as a stream operation.